# Am I being played or what?

Tags: discussion, bounties, accepted-answer

**The Problem**

I recently participated in a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21913504/accessibility-settings-for-non-gui-apps-using-applescript-in-osx-mavericks/22120236#22120236) on SO where after some deliberation I provided a full and concise answer that should have been the accepted solution for the OP. It was up voted and well on it's way to collect a bounty. Then as the bounty expired, my obviously best answer was down voted and awarded to an obviously inferior answer that technically did not supply an answer to the core question (but was a valid workaround).

What makes me feel the situation is a bit *off* is that the bounty was awarded to a new user whose only other reputation were against this question and who joined just a after the  question was posted. At the same time the bounty was awarded, my completely valid question was down voted (?by the OP?). I have seen others post comments when invalid answers are accepted or clearly better answers are not accepted. Is this correct decorum for the environment?

**Next Steps?**

Should I feel gamed or played in this case or make a comment about this? All of which brings me to my next question, Where to go to find out where the latest scams or abuses of the community? Ought there to be a special section that highlights games people play?

Note: Updated this post with the link to the original question.

Comment: You should flag the post or question with a custom flag explaining your concerns and we'll look into it.

Comment: Reviewed... Nothing suspicious found.

Comment: If the OP wants to give the bounty to another answer they can.  They don't need to downvote your answer to do so.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Good to know. To all, Any thoughts on whether it's appropriate to comment when a selected answer is inferior to another?

Comment: @TommieC. You can comment, but if it's not a constructive comment, it may not stay around.  Comments are ephemeral.  If you're going to leave a comment, make it a really good one, otherwise it's not going t do anyone any good.

Comment: @TommieC. [Sure, why not](http://stackoverflow.com/a/459055/61305)? Read them all. That *was* the accepted answer for years (and only changed due to pressure from comments), and will probably remain the highest voted answer for some time. (I call that "Lemming momentum.") Comments pointing out the problem do not completely offset that, but for those that pay attention, they can avoid implementing something less than optimal.

Answer (score 2):

This question specifically regarded Jenkins, in which the awarded bounty answer demonstrated a simple solution to resolve the issue.

Per the "*new user whose only other reputation were against this question*", that user stated:

> For me this is not a complete solution ... which is how i found this issue

Perhaps their involvement with this issue inspired their first answer.

I wouldn't say your answer is *obviously better* or that theirs is *inferior*; however, providing constructive feedback probably would have helped you to receive the bounty as their answer preexisted yours by 2-days.

Despite the loss of bounty, with your answer only downvoted only once you still gained +28 reputation, as well as +40 rep here.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I believe that the question is titled "Accessibility settings for non-GUI apps using AppleScript in OSX Mavericks?", the Jenkins reference seemed to be secondary to the OP's objective of enabling a specific setting using Applescript. The accepted answer spoke to a workaround using Automator and Jenkins rather than the actual question.  I will try adding more comments in the future to clarify such situations.